# Resume app from background restarts the entire APP?

Tags: iphone, ios, background, storyboard, segue

As described, it looks fine if you background the app and click the app icon again.

BUT if you double click home button and click the app icon from background application icons, your app restarted completely.

I have a menu view, and a game view. Where the menu view has a slider effect for 10sec, and then a start button for the game. and when I click start game, obi it does storyboard segue (model style) to the game view and start the game.

I have code for applicationWillResignActive, and it works fine, as soon as you reactive the game through normal app icon, but from the background app list queue.

Anyone has experienced this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to not putting any slideshow loading in **ViewWillAppear** but in **ViewWillLoad**